# Getting my vue.js app working on IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to finish my very first vue.js mini-app and now I'm stuck with the issue that it is not working in IE11.

Not really sure how/what to so that it works. I tried polyfill, but not sure that I use it correctly...help would be really appreciated, guys!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Selbsttest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row row justify-content-sm-center mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div id="app">

                    <div v-if="step === 0">
                        <div class="row row-eq-height selftest">

                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 q-image" style="background-image:url(img/start.jpg)">
                                <div class="imagecred">Foto: Demo AG/Corbis Images</div>   
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12">

                                <h2 class="pt-4">Wie achtsam gehen Sie mit Ihrem Kind um?</h2>
                                <p>Intro</p>


                                <br />
                                <button @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-info">Test starten</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="" v-for="(q, key) in questions" :value="key">

                        <div v-if="step === q.id">

                            <div class="row row-eq-height selftest">

                                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 q-image" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + q.image + ')' }">
                                    <div class="imagecred">Foto: {{ q.imagecred }} </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 p-0">
                                    <!--<div class="progress">
                                        <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                    </div>-->
                                    <div class=" pr-4 pb-4 pl-4 h-100">
                                        <span class="q-number mt-4 mb-2">Frage {{ q.id }} / 10</span>
                                        <span class="q-title mb-4">{{q.title}}</span>


                                        <div class="form-check" v-for="answer in q.answers">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" v-bind:id="answer.answer" v-bind:value="answer" v-model="q.selectedAnswer">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" v-bind:for="answer.answer">
                                                {{answer.answer}}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                        <div style="text-align: right;" class="mt-4 control-buttons">
                                            <button @click.prevent="prev()" class="btn btn-outline-success">zurück</button>
                                            <button @click.prevent="next()" class="btn btn-success">weiter</button>
                                            <!-- <button @click.prevent="submit()">Save</button>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div v-if="step === 3">
                        <div class="row row-eq-height selftest">

                            <div v-if="total <= 29" class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 q-image" style="background-image: url('img/beobachtend.jpg');">
                                <div class="imagecred">Foto: Demo AG/Fotolia </div>
                            </div>

                            <div v-if="total >= 30 && total <= 44" class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 q-image" style="background-image: url('img/achtsam.jpg');">
                                <div class="imagecred">Foto: Demo AG/Fotolia </div>
                            </div>

                            <div v-if="total >= 45" class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 q-image" style="background-image: url('img/fuersorglich.jpg');">
                                <div class="imagecred">Foto: Demo AG/Fotolia </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 p-0">

                                <div class=" pr-4 pb-4 pl-4">

                                    <p>
                                        !!!Nur fürTest !! Total points: {{total}}
                                    </p>



                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

    <script>
        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                step: 0,
                questions: [
                {
    id: 1,
    image: 'img/q1.jpg',
    imagecred: 'Demo AG/Getty Images',
    title: 'Wie sieht eine gemeinsame Mahlzeit bei Ihnen in der Familie aus?',
    answers: [{
            id: 1,
            answer: 'Wir versuchen möglichst oft gemeinsam zu essen. Smartphones und Spielkonsolen haben dann Pause.',
            points: 3
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            answer: 'Unsere Zeitpläne sind leider so verschieden, dass wir es nicht schaffen gemeinsam zu essen.',
            points: 1
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            answer: 'Wir haben feste Zeiten für unser gemeinsames Essen. Jeder erzählt dann von seinem Tag.',
            points: 6
        }
    ],
    selectedAnswer: ''
}, {
    id: 2,
    image: 'img/q2.jpg',
    imagecred: 'Demo AG/Corbis Images',
    title: 'Ihr Kind ist seit klein auf in einem Schwimmverein und hat schon einige Wettkämpfe gewonnen. Sie haben erfahren, dass das Kind in letzter Zeit mehrfach das Training geschwänzt hat, um mit Freunden Fußball zu spielen. Was tun Sie?',
    answers: [{
            id: 1,
            answer: 'Ich spreche mit meinem Kind über sein Verhalten und erkläre ihm, dass es wichtig ist, diszipliniert an seinen Talenten zu arbeiten.',
            points: 6
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            answer: 'Schwimmen scheint ihm keinen Spaß mehr zu machen. Ich  melde es vom Training ab.',
            points: 1
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            answer: 'Ich frage mein Kind, warum es nicht mehr zum Schwimmtraining gehen mag. Vielleicht hat das Schwänzen keinen sportlichen Hintergrund, sondern persönliche Hintergründe wie z.B. einen Streit. Wenn es wirklich lieber Fußball spielen will, ist das aber auch in Ordnung.  ',
            points: 3
        }
    ],
    selectedAnswer: ''
}],
                selected: []
            },
            computed: {
                total() {
                    let points = 0;
                    this.questions.forEach(q => {
                        points += q.selectedAnswer ? q.selectedAnswer.points : 0;
                    });
                    return points;
                }
            },
            methods: {
                showAnswer(selectedAnswer) {
                    if (selectedAnswer) {
                        return 'Selected: ' + selectedAnswer.answer + ', points: ' + selectedAnswer
                            .points
                    }
                    return '';
                },

                prev() {
                    this.step--;
                },
                next() {
                    this.step++;
                },
                submit() {
                    alert('Submit to blah and show blah and etc.');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

It a test with several steps as well as a rating function.

Comment: Do not use jsfiddle.Post your code here

Comment: just added code on here

Comment: Basically, to get it to work in IE, you need to remove all the ES6 code.

Comment: @Bert – but wouldn't it be possible to use babel or so to make it work? Even with ES6...I have a lack in understanding how to solve this issue.

Comment: Sure, you could use babel to compile down to ES5, But basically in your code you are using `let` and `const` which are not supported in IE. Neither can you use ES6 [method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). You will need to use the older syntax (`methods: { showAnswer: function(selectedAnswer) { ... } } `). No fat arrow functions either.

Comment: @Bert - thanks for the advice. really cool. Used the babel compiler and it gave me an old syntax and now its working!!! Awesome!